# How can I append text to a div as a user types and have it update live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slide creation application where a user can enter markdown and preview said markdown as the user enters text. I am using the [uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/htmleditor.html) HTML editor with markdown mode.

You can preview the application [here](http://3dslides.elasticbeanstalk.com/create).

I also want to be able grab the `innerHTML` of the document with the `id` of `markDownPre`and append that to a preview of the slide (located in the image below) which the user is creating (I am currently doing this and you can see that code below)

```
var slidePre = document.getElementById('markDownPre').innerHTML;
var slidePreText = slidePre.split('<hr>', 1);
if (colorScheme[theme] === colorScheme["Tron Blue"]) {
  $('.slide-preview img:last-child' ).remove();
  $('.slide-preview video:last-child' ).remove();
  $('.slide-preview').append('<img src=' + themePreview[0] + ' />');
  $('.slide-preview').append('<div id="slidePreTextTron" class="col-md-3">' + slidePreText + '</div>');
}
```

My issue is that I want to be able to get the text as the user types it, so that it live updates the `<div>` with the id `slidePreTextTron` window with the same text that is updated in the`div` with the `class` of `uk-htmleditor-preview`. How can I accomplish this?

Here is an image of what the small preview window looks like:
[image]

I uploaded this image because it is not implemented currently in the deployed version of the app, rather in the development branch of the Github repo which you can grab [here](https://github.com/jshuadvd/RTVS360/tree/development).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an onchange handler on the input field?

Comment: @DanielBeck I had this http://jsbin.com/jaceje/edit?js,console
But that wasn't working for me.

Comment: By any chance is `#markDownPre` a contentEditable node instead of a form input?  If so you may want the `input` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I also need to split the string with this `var slidePreText = slidePre.split('<hr>', 1);`

Comment: @DanielBeck `#markDownPre` is basically a `textarea` created by codemirror. Is there anyway you can show me how to implement what you mean by altering the function I showed you? I know I have the `input` in the `on` listener.

Comment: Oh, heck, sorry, I missed that you were using a pre-built editor.  If it's a textarea then $('#markDownPre').on('change') should work, but only if the textarea exists before you assign the handler -- it's possible you're trying to attach the handler before codemirror creates its textarea. (You could work around that with event delegation from a known parent element, or by delaying your own code execution until after the editor has done its init.)

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks. The text editor definitely exists because the other input is updating and I am able to grab the input from the initial updated `<div>`. The problem is that when a user continues to type after the page has loaded and theme is selected, the appended text only updates in the editor preview, but not the small window at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the nitpicking about code style is kind of irrelevant to the question. jQuery's `.html()` actually uses `innerHTML` internally...

Comment: @jshuadvd at this point then I'm afraid I'm stumped, unless you can extract the html and the code that is supposed to update the slide preview and include it here. (Sorry, I'm not going to dig through your github repo.)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the single comment was also irrelevant to the question. And didn't need further clarification.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks for all of your help. I really appreciate the troubleshooting with you. I understand about digging through the repo. I'll extract out the HTML and shoot you a link to it shortly. Thanks again!